# How to start top menu by some specific category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, topmenu

How to start **top menu** by some `specific category ID` in **magento 2**.

Something like this in `topmenu.phtml`

```
<?php 
$categoryID = 6;
$_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit, $categoryID); 
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the exact requirement? You want like if top category start is A,B,C,D.E then you want to start top category from C, means C,D,E will only show at frontend?

Answer (score 1):

At magento2, the categories coming at the menu, it renderer plugin class `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu:beforeGetHtml`.

This plugin is created over `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` class.

If you want to start from a certain category then you have to work on that function.

So, if want to change the behaviour then you have to create around plugin on `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu:beforeGetHtml` means plugin over plugin :)

**I have suggested `around` plugin because it has full capacity to change a function return and it business running over it**

Answer (score -1):

If you want to start from a certain category then you have to work on that function.

So, if want to change the behaviour then you have to create around plugin on Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu:beforeGetHtml means plugin over plugin :

catalogCategory = $catalogCategory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    /**
     * @param FirstMenu $subject
     * @param string $outermostClass
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @param int $limit
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function beforeGetHtml(
        FirstMenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
       
        $rootId =3;
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->getCategoryTree($storeId, $rootId);
        $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        $mapping = [$rootId => $subject->getMenu()];  // use nodes stack to avoid recursion
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $categoryParentId = $category->getParentId();
            if (!isset($mapping[$categoryParentId])) {
                $parentIds = $category->getParentIds();
                foreach ($parentIds as $parentId) {
                    if (isset($mapping[$parentId])) {
                        $categoryParentId = $parentId;
                    }
                }
            }

            /** @var Node $parentCategoryNode */
            $parentCategoryNode = $mapping[$categoryParentId];

            $categoryNode = new Node(
                $this->getCategoryAsArray(
                    $category,
                    $currentCategory,
                    $category->getParentId() == $categoryParentId
                ),
                'id',
                $parentCategoryNode->getTree(),
                $parentCategoryNode
            );
            $parentCategoryNode->addChild($categoryNode);

            $mapping[$category->getId()] = $categoryNode; //add node in stack
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param FirstMenu $subject
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function beforeGetIdentities(FirstMenu $subject)
    {
        $subject->addIdentity(Category::CACHE_TAG);
        $rootId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->getCategoryTree($storeId, $rootId);
        $mapping = [$rootId => $subject->getMenu()];  // use nodes stack to avoid recursion
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            if (!isset($mapping[$category->getParentId()])) {
                continue;
            }
            $subject->addIdentity(Category::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $category->getId());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get current Category from catalog layer
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    private function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        $catalogLayer = $this->layerResolver->get();

        if (!$catalogLayer) {
            return null;
        }

        return $catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
    }

    /**
     * Convert category to array
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $currentCategory
     * @param bool $isParentActive
     * @return array
     */
    private function getCategoryAsArray($category, $currentCategory, $isParentActive)
    {
        $categoryId = $category->getId();
        return [
            'name' => $category->getName(),
            'id' => 'category-node-' . $categoryId,
            'url' => $this->catalogCategory->getCategoryUrl($category),
            'has_active' => in_array((string)$categoryId, explode('/', (string)$currentCategory->getPath()), true),
            'is_active' => $categoryId == $currentCategory->getId(),
            'is_category' => true,
            'is_parent_active' => $isParentActive
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Category Tree
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param int $rootId
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function getCategoryTree($storeId, $rootId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setStoreId($storeId);
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => '1/2/' . $rootId . '/%']); //load only from store root
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        $collection->addNavigationMaxDepthFilter();
        $collection->addUrlRewriteToResult();
        $collection->addOrder('level', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        $collection->addOrder('position', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        $collection->addOrder('parent_id', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        $collection->addOrder('entity_id', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * @param FirstMenu $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetCacheKeyInfo(FirstMenu $subject, array $result)
    {
        $activeCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($activeCategory) {
            $result[] = Category::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $activeCategory->getId();
        }

        return $result;
    }
}